# How do I setup HTTP artifact binding in ADFS 3.0?

Tags: binding, adfs, google-search-appliance, resolver

I am trying to understand what are the steps involved in enabling HTTP artifact binding in ADFS 3.0 that could resolve my SAML assertion sending via GSA (Google Search Appliance). I need to provide an "Artifact Resolver URL" to GSA. so I need to know what steps are involved in ADFS 3.0 to make this URL working.

I see below document that talks about this in section 4.8, but that did not help me and also it is for ADFS 2.0.

http://download.microsoft.com/documents/France/Interop/2010/Using_ADFS2_0_For_Interoperable_SAML_2_0-Based_Federated_SSO.docx

```
https://SAML-hostname:port/saml-bridge/Resolve.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps for ADFS 2 and 3 are much the same.

You have to run ADFS on SQL Server not WID.

The process is described here: [SP-initiated Single Sign-On POST/Artifact Bindings](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/sp-initiated-single-sign-on-postartifact-bindings).

Also ADFS is a SP not an IDP in this scenario.

Basically:

- ADFS send AuthnRequest
- User authenticates on IDP
- When ADFS gets successful response, sends artifact to IDP by back-channel WS-Trust SOAP connection
- IDP replies with assertions (claims)

Comment: Does anything in SAML exists which allows no-browser interactions? You capture username:password and then talk with IdP whit out browser?

Comment: There is a SAML profile that allows it but I don't know of anyone that has implemented it.

Comment: Also there is PAOS (reverse SOAP) but again rarely implemented.

Comment: Thanks bud, that's exactly what I'm finding out... a lot of mentions about SAML ECP profile but no implementation examples.